# UDP unicast more reliable than broadcast?

Tags: network-programming, udp, broadcast, multicast, unicast

We have a network engine which currently supports both unicast and broadcast - we have been using unicast up to now, but I'm exploring the broadcast capability in an effort to reduce network traffic.

My tests seem to suggest that unicasting is *far* more reliable than broadcasting - this isn't something I was expecting to see (I don't have a strong networking background).

For example, with a simple test scenario where packets are sent from a host to a client across a gigabit ethernet LAN - I can unicast 15,000 1000 byte packets every second with no packet loss. If I switch to broadcasting, I can only manage about 1200 1000 byte packets before encountering +/- 20% packet loss.

Is this expected? I haven't been able to find a clear answer to this specific question while reading through info on the differences between unicasting and broadcasting.

If this is indeed expected behvaiour, would multicasting be more akin to unicasting than broadcasting in this respect ('reliability')?

**Test Details**

I've whipped up an app which allows various settings to be manipulated (send rate, packet size, number of packets sent per 'iteration', etc.). I run several instances of this app locally and then some more instances on other PCs on the network (I have run with just a single instance on my PC and another PC).

Each packet contains the name of the app instance it was sent from, an integer ID (that is incremented each time the app sends a packet) and a payload (typically 0, 500, 1000 or 1400 bytes big).

When a packet is received the ID field is inspected and I determine if it is the expected ID (I track the next ID I expect to receive from each app instance). An ID that is later than what I'm expecting indicates packets have been lost or are arriving out-of-sequence, an ID earlier than what I'm expecting indicates the packet has arrived out-of-sequence.

The send rate can be modified, by default I use a 20ms delay. The number of packet sent each time can be modified too - so I can, for example, specify that I want to send 50 packets every 20ms (each packet would have a unique ID).

Comment: I'd be interested to see your methodology. Are you measuring broadcast packet loss across all participants?

Comment: @EJP yes I am, interestingly loss occurs even on participants that are running on the same PC. I'll try elaborate in the question.

Comment: How are you pacing the transmission? Do you measure how much time has elapsed since the last time you sent, compute how many packets to send, send that many, and then sleep for as little time as possible? Or what? The details make a *huge* difference with multicast, since there's no feedback even locally.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz the test app just has a simple delay at this point, however the production software uses proper timing management.

Comment: My bet is that your timing is the issue. And, I might add, it may not be all that possible to get the timing to be all that much better. If you're trying to send 1,000 packets per second and evenly pace them, you need to run every millisecond, which is not practical on a modern, general-purpose OS. Sending a bunch at a time, as you see, leads to packet loss.

Comment: My question is more that this appears to work fine for unicasting (even with fairly extreme loads) - why is broadcast so 'unreliable' by contrast? If this isn't expected behaviour, then I'd imagine there's probably a problem in our network engine.

Comment: Are there a large number of non-participating nodes on the network?  If so you're actually sending a lot more packets than you are with unicast.

Comment: @xaxxon by non-participating do you mean nodes that are only receiving packets and not sending OR machines just happen to be on the network and are not involved in my tests? If the former, than I wouldn't say there are many - my tests typically involved about 7 nodes. If the latter, than yes there are probably between 50 and 100 other machines (not sure if this counts as 'large number').

Comment: "machines just happen to be on the network"  They still have to have the packets generated and sent to them, so that's overhead on the network gear.   If you were already near the limits, broadcasting with these additional hosts could put you over.   Try your test again on a LAN with only participating nodes and see if you see a change.

Comment: The network utilization (including that of the non-participating hosts) also impacts your results.   You should be doing any type of benchmarking like this on a controlled network anyhow.

Comment: @xaxxon I don't have access to an ideal test environment right now, but I've pulled my PC from the LAN and run some tests with local nodes only and it supports what you've said - broadcast actually becomes less lossy than unicast (as I'd expect). I'll still try it in a proper LAN environment, but if you post an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send a UDP broadcast to the network, the packet must be duplicated and sent to every node on the network creating significant work for the network device.   If your LAN consists of a large number of devices which were not previously being unicast to, doing a full broadcast can create a lot more network activity and work for the network devices.

However, if your network is entirely made up of nodes desiring participation, I would expect the broadcast option to be more reliable, as the network device is receiving less data from the source and is able to run optimized procedures for sending out broadcast packets to the same number of hosts as it would have if the packets were individually unicasted.

When doing network testing it's important to use a controlled environment where you can understand the variables involved and see how different types of scaling impact your performance.